# Facebook likebox shows up when page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am busy with migrating a small project from basic-coding to a framework with better code quality. That goes very well and I am almost finished.

The only problem that I have, is with the Facebook "Like and share box".
When I load my page, the page loads very fast. But 1 second later, Facebook appears and that is very annoying.

I already tried to speed it up, with asynchronous loading, but that did'nt solve the problem.

**Facebook Javascript:**

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.async=true;    
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1528564797406699";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**Facebook "Like and share box"**

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://zoekeenleven.be" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Live example: http://beta.zoekeenleven.be/

Can anyone help me with this? I want Facebook to load together with the page, and not afterwards.

Comment: Async loading is the default, and already implemented with the code you get from the FB developer section. _“I want Facebook to load together with the page, and not afterwards”_ – well then you _don’t_ want async loading ... You can of course embed the SDK via a script element directly, instead of using the above code. (But that is not _really_ recommendable - f.e. if Facebook is down, your site will “hang” as well.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for helping me! And how can I embed it directly? I love the speed of my webpage and want everything with the same speed. Also the third-party plugins.

Comment: By not creating a script element dynamically and embedding it as the above code does, but instead using a simple `<script src="..."></script>` to embed the SDK into the document. (But the elements you want it to transform into social plugins must exist at that point already.)